# Android How To I Detect Application Resume from Sleep and Send App to main page -restart

Tags: android, sleep

After my application sleeps, when it resumes I don't want it to go back to the last activity it was on but to start fresh from the main activity as a new fresh start.  How can this be done? I also want it to be fresh start in terms not just of being on first activivity but also fresh in start in terms of session etc.  How can this be done?  Where would I detect the resume and how to go back to start.  Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, I hate it when Android apps do this!  If my phone goes to sleep or I switch away from an app, I do not want my apps to lose where I was and act like they've restarted.

Answer (score 0):

> Where would I detect the resume and how to go back to start

You could use events OnResume, OnPause etc. I would suggest you simply finish your app when it goes from foreground:

```
protected void onPause() {  //Another activity comes to the foreground or other apps need memory
    super.onPause();

    SaveSettings();    //Your own method
    finish();
}
```